# How to import a .txt file into a mysql database in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am interested to import this 5000 line .txt file into a mysql database.

```html
 P|1|A PRODUCT|1|0002000|204|123|
 P|2|ANOTHER PRODUCT|10000371|0001990|055|031|
 B|055|A BRAND NAME|
 B|204|ANOTHER BRAND NAME|
 G|123|GROUP NAME|
 G|031|ANOTHER GROUP NAME|
```

Where P means that line refers to a "Product" table, B means "Brand" table and G means "Group". I need them separatedly in the database.
If it's impossible to do it only with sql, there is some way i'll get the result I want using PHP?

Comment: I am afraid you are going to have to wriite a script to do this.

Comment: Is this a one-off import or a process that will happen often? Do you have your table structure for `Product`, `Brand` and `Group`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the php explode will do the job for you, here is how

```
$data = file_get_contents('data.txt')
// make an array for each line
$lines = explode('/n', $data)
foreach ($lines as $line) {
// Make array  for each part of the line
$eline = explode('|', $line) ;
// $eline[0] is first part that have b or g or p
if ($eline[0] == 'B') {
// the sql code for brands
}
}
```

if you want i can complete the full code for you just tell me what the sql querys

Answer (score -1):

It would be easiest if the file was separated by type. I'd use grep because its there already and saves writing the same functionality in php:

```
grep ^P file.txt > P.txt
grep ^G file.txt > G.txt
grep ^B file.txt > B.txt
```

[LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) can be used to import each individual file into its own table. Ensure `mysql` client is started with `--local-infile` to allow it to pass the file.